# Allowed for notification yet permission === 'granted' returns false

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am setting up a Firebase client for JavaScript. When asked for notification permission I allow it, but it still returns `false`.

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

//Request permission to receive notifications
messaging.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
    // ...
  } else {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
  }
});
```

I get the following in my console "Unable to get permission to notify." when I click on allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#request-permission):

> The promise resolves if permission is granted. Otherwise, the promise is rejected with an error.

So instead of checking the passed parameter, you should check whether the promise is resolved or rejected:

```
messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.');
  // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
  // ...
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
});
```

That being said, according to the documentation the `requestPermission()` is deprecated and should be replaced with [`Notification.requestPermission()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission). That one looks more the way you tried it:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
    // ...
  } else {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
  }
});
```